# Windows Store App template does not create BooleanToVisibilityConverter in common

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I am using VS2013 and creating a windows store app (windows 8.1) from the templates.  Many references show that there is a BooleanToVisibilityConverter  class being created in the common folder that can be referenced it the xaml but the class is not created in my common folder.  I get NavigationHelper, ObservableDictionary, RelayCommand, and SuspensionManager but not BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

So what am I missing about this?

Answer (score 0):

Templates can be changed from version to version. So, create it by hands:

```
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
    {
        return ( value is bool && ( bool )value ) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
    {
        return value is Visibility && ( Visibility )value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```